# What are some python packages I can use to cut audio files

Tags: audio, python, speech-processing

I have a project in which I have a batch of audio files and I need to remove the audio in it from say time 2secs to 5secs i.e. I have a set duration to be removed. How can I do this in python?

Comment: What file format?

Comment: Why not to use sox for that? No need to involve Python in my opinion.

Comment: the format is .wav @endolith. Also I need to further process the audio and hence I want to do the process in python

Answer (score 1):

The librosa library is usually used. You can find the files here:

https://github.com/librosa/librosa

Answer (score 1):

The most basic approach probably would be to use `scipy`'s [read](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html#scipy.io.wavfile.read) and [write](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html) functions for wave files.

An interesting alternative is to use the [SoundFile](https://pypi.org/project/SoundFile/) library. As SoundFile is based on libsndfile, a large number of audio formats is supported.